# Telerik radgrid row color issue

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik

In my code I have this sub to handle changing row colors depending on the contents of a column called "backorder" which is bit in sqlserver.
When I test if it is True or 1 it executes the main "IF" code twice which is correct for my datatable. 2 rows display as backorder = True. However the grid remains the normal color. If I uncomment the else code block, ALL cells in that column are orange regardless of content and the execution still passed thru the main "IF" twice. I am quite confused by this behavior. If it was CSS interfering, why would it let the orange color work? I have tried a dozen variations of code which all posters say should work...

Please help! I have spent most of the day trying to unravel this!

```
Protected Sub RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs) Handles RadGrid1.ItemDataBound
    If TypeOf e.Item Is GridDataItem Then
        Dim item As GridDataItem = DirectCast(e.Item, GridDataItem)
        If item("backorder").Text = "True" Or item("backorder").Text = "1" Then
            item("backorder").BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
        Else
            'item("backorder").BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `item("backorder")` returns an object of type `TableCell`, not a row. Therefore, when setting `item("backorder").BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red` you are setting the cell in the column backorder's BackColor, not the entire rows backcolor. If the Column backorder is not visible, you wont see any change.

Try the following code:

```
Protected Sub RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs) Handles RadGrid1.ItemDataBound
If TypeOf e.Item Is GridDataItem Then
     Dim item As GridDataItem = DirectCast(e.Item, GridDataItem)
     If item("backorder").Text = "True" Or item("backorder").Text = "1" Then
         item.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red
     Else
         item.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange
     End If
End If
End Sub
```

What this does is check the column 'backorder', and then sets the entire rows BackColor by setting the BackColor for the `GridDataItem`.

Check out Shinu's answer in the following post. [Telerik Forum Post](http://www.telerik.com/forums/rad-grid-change-row-background-color#X4oh48gSP0ymYFyEpcac5A)

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to the Boolean evaluation you're doing.  You've accounted for "True" and 1, but there are others:  "true", and -1 come immediately to mind.  You might try this instead:

```
Protected Sub RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs) Handles RadGrid1.ItemDataBound
    If TypeOf e.Item Is GridDataItem Then
        Dim item As GridDataItem = DirectCast(e.Item, GridDataItem)
        If  Convert.ToBoolean(item("backorder").Text) = True Then
            item("backorder").BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
        Else
            item("backorder").BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

That way, you're letting the built-in Convert object handle the heavy-lifting on the "truthiness" of the statement contained in the string.

Comment: In debug, it displays "True" as text, but it IS finding those and passing thru that block of code twice! Once for each item that is back ordered yet the color doesn't change! I will however try converting to bool.

Comment: Duh, the "everything turned orange" case was a different issue. However, it passes thru the if as "true" and the attempt to color it red does not work... The "else" block was put in diagnostically...